# R shiny: Check if some download is available

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

Suppose I have a shiny application that has a download button, and I want to check if that download button has received a file, how can I do it? Basically if the download button has a tag `download1`, I want to check if `output$download1` is null. This is basically an example of what I'm trying to do. It's a simplified version of my current application, and I know that checking if `output$download1` is null is not necessary in my case, but I need it for something else that I am doing. Is that doable?

This is my server file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({

    shinyjs::disable("download1")

    if(is.null(input$file1))
      return()

    # download data
    data <- mtcars
    output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file)
      }
    )

    shinyjs::enable("download1")

    # Check if download is there
     if(!is.null(output$download1)){ # This is what doesn't work
       # Do something
     }

  })

})
```

and the ui file:

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    fileInput("file1", "Upload file1"),
    downloadButton("download1"),
    helpText("Download after something is done.")

))
```

Comment: First, your download button is disabled. You can create a `reactiveValue` which will keep track of whether the download file is ready. Then you use an `observe` function to actually create the file. This observer will switch the `reactiveValue`, which in turn will activate the download button. The `downloadHandler` then just has to copy the prepared file.

Comment: @mRcSchwering Ok thanks I got it!